# Fireplace gas line burner replacement

Tags: plumbing, fireplace, natural-gas, gas-burner

So in an effort to update my fireplace I was looking to remove the old burner meant for a gas log set and install an H-burner for a fire glass setup.  The original nipple was too long traveling into the box and would have been unsafe so hacked off a couple of inches.

[image: Fire Box]

My original plan was to rethread the pipe but the more I started thinking about it I figured just removing the pipe entirely would make more sense.  Well the issue is the pipe won't budge with a 12" pipe wrench and I'm hesitant to start really wailing on it not knowing the actual setup within the wall.  The pipe is about 17" to the next fitting, which I assume to be an elbow.  The shut-off valve is of course on the other side of the fireplace so I'm assuming it elbows around the back of the fireplace and wraps back around to where it exits into box.

Am I fool trying to complete this blindly and should just bite the bullet and try to get access from the outdoor wall?  Or the interior drywall?  I've attached pictures for opinions.

[image: Interior Side]

[image: Exterior Side]

Comment: You are trying to turn it counterclockwise.. right?

Comment: Yes...I am trying to loosen the pipe.  Which is a bit of the issue as I'm having to push towards the firebox.  It would of course be easier if I was pulling towards space.

Comment: Are you sure the other end is threaded? If so, it could be installed with a hard set pipe compound. Very difficult to break. Can you get the pipe wrench situated so you're applying upward? It so, try slipping a length of pipe on the handle to extend your leverage.

Comment: Hadn't even though about it possibly being hard set. Home was built in 1976 and I'm pretty sure no one has touched the pipes since then. I can definitely get some cheater action going but if I do and it is hard set is it likely I could damage something further upstream before the compound gives? The pipe being 17 in to the joint isn't helping matters of torque I'm sure.

Comment: @DrSparks see above

Comment: Could you take a closeup picture of the pipe? Yes you could damage something if you don't use a holdback wrench. You could break a connection to the gas valve. Might be best to see what's going on on the other side of the wall.